# How to make new line input message by pressing shift + enter? Angular

Tags: html, angular, input, text, chat

I have a chat box with a single input field. I want to make handle new line input like Facebook's chatbox.

**My Chat Box:**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeG7d.png

**My HTML of input field:**

```
<form class="form" #msgForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="send(msgForm)" focus>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="form-control left-border-none"
          name="message" [(ngModel)]="message" placeholder="Say Something..."
          (input)="onChange($event.target.value)" />
        <span class="input-group-addon transparent">
          <button type="submit" (keyup.enter)="send(msgForm)"
            style="border: 0; background: none;cursor: pointer;"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" [hidden]="isHidden" 
            style="font-size:20px;color:  #6d5cae;"></i></button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use textarea instead of input field?

Comment: Yes, but when i replace with textarea, its container doesn't increase height dynamiclly <div class="input-group"> is container. do you know how?

Comment: You can refer this page https://material.angular.io/cdk/text-field/examples

``` <textarea matInput
            cdkTextareaAutosize
            #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
            cdkAutosizeMinRows="1"
            cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"></textarea>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution.

> **Brief Note**
>  It's not the exact answer because I had the same problem and after a lot of testing, found more adequate to let "Enter" for newlines and"Shift+Enter" for sending messages
>
> This is the opposite logic of popular apps like WS and MSg but I found
> more suitable for people having a conversations over a web based chat, since in a conversation you want sometimes to write long messages, and for people habituated to type on text editors, this is the logic function of pushing "Enter".
> People may disagree, but just hope you can find it useful

What I did was to using a text-area as container, for easier auto-sizing and multi-line configuration

After that, I created a button that posts the message once clicked,and a `@Hostlistener` for the event to bind the button to the method.

Please refer to the code.

Best regards

HTML from the typing bar component

```html
<!-- (keydown)="onKey($event)" -->
<!-- submit message with enter -->
<!-- (keydown.enter)="postMessage(messageContainer)" -->
<!-- (keyup.enter)="onKeydown($event)" // for event methods -->

<div class="typing-bar prim-color" >
  <textarea

    matInput
    matAutosize
    name=""

    cdkTextareaAutosize
    #messageContainer
    #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
    cdkAutosizeMinRows="2"
    cdkAutosizeMaxRows="7"
  >
  </textarea>
  <button
  mat-stroked-button
  color="accent"
  (click)="postMessage(messageContainer)"
  [disabled]="messageContainer.value===''"
  ><mat-icon>send</mat-icon> Send</button>

</div>
```

TS Code for the component

```js
import { Component, HostListener, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-typing-bar',
  templateUrl: './typing-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./typing-bar.component.scss']
})
export class TypingBarComponent implements OnInit {

  displayBar: boolean = true;



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  @HostListener('body:keydown.shift.enter',['$event'])launchPost($event: KeyboardEvent): void{
    return this.postMessage($event.target as HTMLTextAreaElement)
  }

  postMessage(textarea:HTMLTextAreaElement){
    //post message here
    // ....logic...

    //reset textarea
    textarea.value = ""

    //give focus back
    textarea.focus();

    //debug: this is for test only. Delete after testing
    alert('sent')
  }

}
```

SCSS code for the component (maybe not the final version)

```css
.typing-bar{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin: 1px;

  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}


textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 93%;
//   max-height: 20%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

// .typing-bar button{

// }
```